# I dont know how to insert to access database input type = "date" please

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, database

I have a website and I did asp:button and added asp:textbox inside the database and it worked. 
But when I tried an insert on  , it's not working to me. I am trying to write insert date.text to my database in aspx.cs and it's finding the id of that because it's an input and not asp:textbox.

```html
<td class="style4">
    תאריך לידה:
</td>
<td class="style3">
    <input id="date" type="Date" min="1905-01-01" max="2019-01-01" value="2018-01-01"/>
</td>
```

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\WebSites\MyWebsite\DataBase.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = "insert into users (FirstName, LastName, Place, Email, UserName, Birthday) values('" + firstname.Text + "','" + lastname.Text + "','" + PlaceList.Text + "','" + MyEmail.Text + "','" + AccountText.Text + "','" + date.Text + "')";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And I am getting an error :

> Error 29  The name 'date' does not exist in the current
>   context   F:\WebSites\MyWebsite\Register.aspx.cs  27  242 F:\WebSites\MyWebsite\

It's not finding this id.

Please, can anyone help me solve it ? :(

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the runat property to make element programmable and accessible from code-behind:

```
<input id="date" type="date" runat="server" />
```

Also you should **never-ever** parse user input directly in a query as a parameter because it will inevitably lead you to [security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and other problems (like for example quotes in strings, invalid non-numeric values, the date format based on user locale etc.). Use [command parameters](https://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06) instead:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\WebSites\MyWebsite\DataBase.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;";

try
{
    connection.Open();

    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "insert into users (FirstName, LastName, Place, Email, UserName, Birthday) values(@firstName, @lastName, @placeList, @myMail, @accountText, @date)";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@placeList", placeList.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myMail", myMail.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountText", accountText.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date.Text);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
/* handle various exceptions */
catch (Exception ex)
{
    /*...*/
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need make it `runat = "server"`
Try Now !

```
 <input id="date" type="Date" min="1905-01-01" max="2019-01-01" value="2018-01-01" runat = "server"/>
```

.

```
 OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\WebSites\MyWebsite\DataBase.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    connection.Open();
    command.CommandText = "insert into users (FirstName, LastName, Place, Email, UserName, Birthday) values('" + firstname.Text + "','" + lastname.Text + "','" + PlaceList.Text + "','" + MyEmail.Text + "','" + AccountText.Text + "','" + date.Text + "')";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind you can get form elements by name not by id, so give your input element a name:

```
<input id="date" name = "date" type="Date" min="1905-01-01" max="2019-01-01" value="2018-01-01"/>
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

then it can be accessed by `Request.Form["date"]`:

```
command.CommandText = "insert into users (FirstName, LastName, Place, Email, UserName, Birthday) values('" + firstname.Text + "','" + lastname.Text + "','" + PlaceList.Text + "','" + MyEmail.Text + "','" + AccountText.Text + "','" + Request.Form["date"] + "')";
```

And also note that this input must be inside a form tag.